# What is the closest function to INDEX( ,MATCH( in Google Apps?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a master spreadsheet which has the excel function:
=INDEX(D2:D4,MATCH(F11,B2:B4,0))

How would you express this in Google Apps or is there anything close to it?

Here is the part of the code which needs to be modified:

```
    var link = masterSheet.getRange('F11').getValues();//here is the problem

    //=INDEX(D2:D4,MATCH(F11,B2:B4,0))

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(link);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to achieve the same functionality in Google Apps Script, and if I'm understanding correctly:

```
var lookup = masterSheet.getRange('F11').getValue();
var range = masterSheet.getRange('B2:D4').getValues();
var lookupRange = [];
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) lookupRange.push(range[i][0]);
var index = lookupRange.indexOf(lookup);
if (index == -1) {
  //error, not found
}
else {
  var link = range[index][2];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(link);
  //etc
}
```

Caveat: if you are searching for dates and/or times, this will fail. You will need to convert the date objects into something else that can be found with indexOf. Post back if this is the case.

Comment: Nope, it was simply a link URL which needed to be looked up based upon a single cell reference, so there was no need for dates/times. You have my thanks! You epic genius :)

Answer (score 0):

That same formula should work equally well in both Excel and google spreadsheets, doesn't it work? VLOOKUP could also be used in both to do the same, i.e.

`=vlookup(F11,B2:D4,3,0)`

Comment: Yup, your vlookup does the same trick as index combined with match. Many thanks! However, maybe I needed to rephrase the question because I was wondering if there was the same functionality based in Google Apps.